# How to set font-size to all text in an iFrame when printing with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, printing

I would like set a font-size to all text in an iFrame when printing with Style CSS.

**Change** `font-size as default` **to** `font-size: 20px`. *That is great if you could give me an example with JSFIDDLE.*

Does the iFrame work with the new font-size when I add the Style into this page? Or Should I add the Style in the `href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt'`?

---

**HTML:**

```
<input onclick="printDiv('page_printer');" type="button" value="Print" />

<div id="page_printer">
<iframe id="iframe_link" scrolling="yes" width="200px" height="80px" border="none"></iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    setTimeout(function () { load_iframe(); }, 1500);

function load_iframe() {
    var link = document.getElementById('iframe_link');
    link.setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com");
    var link = $("#iframe_link");
    $(link).attr("src", current_site);
}


function printDiv(divID) {
    var printContent = document.getElementById(divID);
    var windowUrl = '';
    var uniqueName = new Date();
    var windowName = 'Print' ;
    var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=-20,top=-20,width=800px,height=600px');
    printWindow.document.write("<html><head><title></title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/Style%20Library/CarBookingCSS.txt' media='print' />");
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 0px;">');
    printWindow.document.write(printContent.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.focus();
    printWindow.print();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#iframe_link {
    font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

Comment: `#iframe_link *{font-size: 20px !important;}` ???

Comment: @C-link: I've missed it. Now it goes correctly!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is.  If you are asking how to change font size, there are several components involved in that. With CSS [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)  there is a selector, a property, and a value. To change font size of an element the [font-size:](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) property is used in combination with any of several options for setting the [value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp). For some [value types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) there is an added [unit](https://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/) of measure attached at the end.

HTH